# Date change when importing .csv into Oracle table

Tags: oracle, csv, import

I have successfully imported an .csv file into an Oracle Table using SQL Developer. However the date is originally formatted in `YYYYMMDD` but after the import, the date changes from `20050413` to some weird date such as `25550413`. I have also tried importing the data using Toad for Oracle and yielded the same results.

Any thoughts on the culprit? The preview before import on Toad shows the date in correct format. So i know the program is reading the .csv adequately. I keep wondering why does the year mess up like that once it uploads the data onto the Oracle table.

Comment: Substract 550 years from imported data ;-)
And seriously - please add some controversial rows from csv to your question.

Comment: This problem does not make sense at all. Due to the nature of my work, i cannot add some controversial rows on here. The preview before importing onto the Oracle database shows the date as its shown on the csv which is 20050413. I am quite baffled.

Comment: You are not the only one, who has trouble with date importing, for instance [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/775780/Year-and-century-being-swapped-when-inserting-a-da) Importing tools may be bugged. Maybe it's possible to load dates into varchar column at first and then put them in proper date type column?